# Varnish cache is missed after some time

Tags: drupal-8, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

Varnish cache is missed after some time even though the Page cache maximum age in "GENERAL SETTINGS" of Advanced Varnish configuration is set to "1 month"

While overriding the TTL value from individual content type still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors to affect the hit rate of your Varnish server.

Please share the following information:

- The `Cache-Control` headers that your application sends
- The VCL code
- Your `varnishd` runtime parameters and specifically the value of the `-s` parameter
- The output of `varnishstat -f MAIN.n_lru_nuked -f MAIN.n_object -f SMA.*.g_bytes -f SMA.*.g_space`

If there are specific transactions that result in a cache miss but that are supposed to be hits, please run send the output of the following command:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> FYI: This `varnishlog` command filters transactions for the `/` homepage. If the problem occurs on another page, please adjust the `-q` filter.

Based on all this information I can check where the problem is situated.

Comment: This should be a comment, as there is no answer provided. Another relevant question may also be what Drupal module/s are being used to integrate varnish with Drupal and what are their settings.